# Doctrine: Multiple orWhere with LIKE condition

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Use table with structure:

```
id              | count
/string/id1     | 3 
/string/id1/r1  | 2
/string/id1/r2  | 1 
/string/id2/r1  | 2
/string/id2     | 3 
/string/id2/r1  | 2
/string/id3/r1  | 5
```

and I want to select all rows which have needed substring in **id**. 

i.e.
I need all rows which have substring in id:  **/string/id1** and **/string/id2**

The query should be easy - plain sql:

```
select * from table_name where id LIKE '/string/id1%' OR id LIKE '/string/id2%';
```

Result should be:

```
id              | count
/string/id1     | 3 
/string/id1/r1  | 2
/string/id1/r2  | 1
/string/id2/r1  | 2
/string/id2     | 3 
/string/id2/r1  | 2
```

Unfortunately, if you try to use the same query in symfony and doctrine2:

```
$ids = array('/string/id1', '/string/id2');

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
              ->select('r');
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $query->orWhere("r.linkedId LIKE :id ")
        ->setParameter('id', $id."%");
}
$plainQuery = $query->getQuery()->getSQL();
$results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Plain query looks the same like `select * from table_name where id LIKE '/string/id1%' OR id LIKE '/string/id2%';`, but results are not.

results contains only rows of last item in ids - */string/id2*

```
id              | count
/string/id2/r1  | 2
/string/id2     | 3 
/string/id2/r1  | 2
```

How to solve it? Where is my mistake? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin show if you run the raw query? Does it include the right results? If so it seems like a mapping issue on `linkedId` field of your entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot be sure but this seems to me like a conflict with parameter identifiers.

This is what you're trying to do:

- Construct the basic `SELECT * FROM table_name` statement
- Append `WHERE r.linkedId LIKE :id`
- set the value of `id` parameter to `/string/id1%`
- Append `OR r.linkedId LIKE :id`
- **set the value of `id` parameter to `/string/id2%`** (override the previous value) <-- AN ERROR

Basically, you are telling Doctrine to override previously defined value of `id` parameter with new one.

You could easily overcome this issue. Just add `$i` to parameter name

```
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) { 
    // $i here has the value of 0,1,2, etc...

    $query->orWhere("r.linkedId LIKE :id$i" ) // append $i
        ->setParameter("id$i", $id."%"); // but also append it here 
}
```

Be sure to use **double quotes**, or concatenate (`"id" . $i`) instead ;)